# Implementing a "variant" class

Tags: c++

**Note:** I'm aware of `boost::variant`, but I am curious about the design principles. This question mostly for self-education.

#### Original post

At my current job I found an old variant class implementation. It's implemented with a `union` and can only support a handful of datatypes. I've been thinking about how one should go about  designing an improved version. After some tinkering I ended up with something that seems to work. However I'd like to know your opinion about it. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Variant
{
public:
    Variant() { }

    template<class T>
    Variant(T inValue) :
        mImpl(new VariantImpl<T>(inValue)),
        mClassName(typeid(T).name())
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    T getValue() const
    {
        if (typeid(T).name() != mClassName)
        {
            throw std::logic_error("Non-matching types!");
        }

        return dynamic_cast<VariantImpl<T>*>(mImpl.get())->getValue();
    }

    template<class T>
    void setValue(T inValue)
    {
        mImpl.reset(new VariantImpl<T>(inValue));
        mClassName = typeid(T).name();
    }

private:
    struct AbstractVariantImpl
    {
        virtual ~AbstractVariantImpl() {}
    };

    template<class T>
    struct VariantImpl : public AbstractVariantImpl
    {
        VariantImpl(T inValue) : mValue(inValue) { }

        ~VariantImpl() {}

        T getValue() const { return mValue; }

        T mValue;
    };

    boost::shared_ptr<AbstractVariantImpl> mImpl;
    std::string mClassName;
};

int main()
{
    // Store int
    Variant v(10);
    int a = 0;
    a = v.getValue<int>();
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;

    // Store float
    v.setValue<float>(12.34);
    float d = v.getValue<float>();
    std::cout << "d = " << d << std::endl;

    // Store map<string, string>
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Mapping;
    Mapping m;
    m["one"] = "uno";
    m["two"] = "due";
    m["three"] = "tre";
    v.setValue<Mapping>(m);
    Mapping m2 = v.getValue<Mapping>();
    std::cout << "m2[\"one\"] = " << m2["one"] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is correct:

```
a = 10
d = 12.34
m2["one"] = uno
```

My SO questions are:

- Is this implementation correct?
- Will the dynamic cast in `getValue()` work as expected (I'm not certain)
- Should I return T  as a const reference instead? Or can I count on return-value-optimization to kick in?
- Any other problems or suggestions?

#### Update

Thanks to @templatetypedef for his suggestions. This updated version only uses `dynamic_cast` to check if the types match. Type mismatches caused by differences in constness are now avoided thanks to the TypeWrapper classes (which I have shamelessly stolen from the Poco C++ project).

So this is the current version. It's likely to contain a few errors though, as I'm not familiar with the idea of modifying const/ref on template templates. I'll have a fresh look tomorrow.

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeWrapper
{
    typedef T TYPE;
    typedef const T CONSTTYPE;
    typedef T& REFTYPE;
    typedef const T& CONSTREFTYPE;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeWrapper<const T>
{
    typedef T TYPE;
    typedef const T CONSTTYPE;
    typedef T& REFTYPE;
    typedef const T& CONSTREFTYPE;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeWrapper<const T&>
{
    typedef T TYPE;
    typedef const T CONSTTYPE;
    typedef T& REFTYPE;
    typedef const T& CONSTREFTYPE;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeWrapper<T&>
{
    typedef T TYPE;
    typedef const T CONSTTYPE;
    typedef T& REFTYPE;
    typedef const T& CONSTREFTYPE;
};

class Variant
{
public:
    Variant() { }

    template<class T>
    Variant(T inValue) :
        mImpl(new VariantImpl<typename TypeWrapper<T>::TYPE>(inValue))
    {
    }

    template<class T>
    typename TypeWrapper<T>::REFTYPE getValue()
    {
        return dynamic_cast<VariantImpl<typename TypeWrapper<T>::TYPE>&>(*mImpl.get()).mValue;
    }

    template<class T>
    typename TypeWrapper<T>::CONSTREFTYPE getValue() const
    {
        return dynamic_cast<VariantImpl<typename TypeWrapper<T>::TYPE>&>(*mImpl.get()).mValue;
    }

    template<class T>
    void setValue(typename TypeWrapper<T>::CONSTREFTYPE inValue)
    {
        mImpl.reset(new VariantImpl<typename TypeWrapper<T>::TYPE>(inValue));
    }

private:
    struct AbstractVariantImpl
    {
        virtual ~AbstractVariantImpl() {}
    };

    template<class T>
    struct VariantImpl : public AbstractVariantImpl
    {
        VariantImpl(T inValue) : mValue(inValue) { }

        ~VariantImpl() {}

        T mValue;
    };

    boost::shared_ptr<AbstractVariantImpl> mImpl;
};
```

Comment: I tried to implement the `std::ostream& operator<<(const Variant& v)` in order to be able to `cout << v;` as could be done with boost::variant. However I did not succeed to write anything that does not require the type specification when calling the operator. I wonder how this is achieved in boost, I tried to look at the sources but they were not illuminating.

Comment: @DarioP You can add a virtual method called "print" to AbstractVariantImpl and implement it in VariantImpl. Then you can implement operator<< for Variant as a (inline) friend function.

Comment: Yes, that seemed the natural solution to me as well. However once you write the operator<< inside of Variant you cannot store any more objects for which the operator<< is not defined. I also tried the free function but it is not visible in the template definition and clang does not compile (gcc does but I don't trust it so much). I spent quite few hours on this but no result :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This implementation is close to correct, but it looks like it has a few bugs.  For example, this code:

```
if (typeid(T).name() != mClassName)
```

is not guaranteed to work correctly because the `.name()` function in `type_info` is not guaranteed to return a unique value for each type.  If you want to check if the types match, you should probably use something like this:

```
if (typeid(*mImpl) == typeid(VariantImpl<T>))
```

Which more accurately checks if the type matches.  Of course, you need to watch out for `const` issues, since storing a `const T` and storing a `T` will yield different types.

As for your question about `dynamic_cast`, in the case you've described you don't need to use the `dynamic_cast` because you already have a check to confirm that the type will match.  Instead, you can just use a `static_cast`, since you've already caught the case where you have the wrong type.

More importantly, though, what you've defined here is an "unrestricted variant" that can hold absolutely anything, not just a small set of restricted types (which is what you'd normally find in a variant).  While I really like this code, I'd suggest instead using something like Boost.Any or Boost.Variant, which has been extensively debugged and tested.  That said, congrats on figuring out the key trick that makes this work!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are probably right about using Boost. However, I do want to ask a few questions: 1. How do you know that the second version will more accurately match the types? 2. I tried to avoid const issues by always returning T by value. Is this the right way to go? 3. I could also skip the classname test and only rely on the dynamic_cast test instead. Which would you prefer?

Comment: @StackedCrooked- 1. The `==` operator on `type_info` actually compares whether they represent the same types, independently of the display names they use.  It's the correct way to do the matching.  If you were to compare by string name, there's no guarantee that it would work correctly; I could implement `type_info::name` to always return the empty string and be standards-compliant.  2. Unfortunately, that's not strong enough, since when you're storing a `VariantImpl<const T>` it's a different type than a `VariantImpl<T>` and the cast won't work (continued in next post...)

Comment: @StackedCrooked- 2. ctd. You are probably best off using a metafunction to remove const from the type.  3. I'd suggest using the `dynamic_cast`, since this can also be configured to throw a `std::bad_cast` exception if the cast fails.  However, be sure that you handle `const`ness correctly!

Comment: @templatetypedef: I made a few modifications according to your suggestions. Feel free to comment. I'm off for tonight :)

Comment: @StackedCrooked- This looks great, though I'm curious why you're storing `REFTYPE` and `CONSTREFTYPE` in those specialization if you're not using them.  Otherwise this looks really cool!

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of providing a non-answer, since you are already using Boost, I recommend you try Boost.Variant or Boost.Any instead of rolling your own implementation.

Comment: I'm aware of these options. I may eventually choose to use them instead of implementing it myself. However, I'm also asking this question because I want to learn .

Comment: +1, provided answers are not just for the benefit of the questioner.  Of course you don't implement your own, that's just silly.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use `std::auto_ptr`, as there's no reference counting semantics required. I would normally return by reference as it's perfectly legal to change the value within, or by pointer to allow NULL.

You should use `dynamic_cast` to match types, not `typeid()`, and you could just use Boost. `typeid()` seems like it should provide this but in reality it doesn't because of the open-endedness of it's specification, whereas `dynamic_cast` is always exactly and unambiguously correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using auto_ptr seems risky unless I make my class non-copyable. Wouldn't a scoped_ptr be safer instead? (Assuming boost is available).

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the copy semantics of this class should be, IMO. As it is, the stored value is read-only, so sharing a single instance seems reasonable. Otherwise, if you decide the value should be modifiable and each copy should have it's own stored value, `shared_ptr` has little use and a simpler `scoped_ptr` might be better. - If I'm not mistaken, boost's `any` also uses typeid. If you want to throw your own exception, then it seems sensible not to use `dynamic_cast` only to catch `bad_cast` and throw your own exception instead.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: I'd forgotten about the copying semantics. Yes, that would likely be better. I use `unique_ptr` on my C++0x compiler so, the issue is gone for me. @UncleBens: `bad_cast` seems like a perfectly good exception to throw in this instance.

Comment: Thanks, my current implementation only checks with dynamic_cast now.