# How to implement simple class with variant field in c++

Tags: c++, variant

I want to implement class which let's say have field key and class A or B.
The argument in constructor in this class is array of chars.
The constructor pseudocode would take a look at first char, if it is exual to 0x00 it will create class A object,
otherwise it will create class B object - both classes will take the array of chars as argument.

Anyway I want to keep this implementation simple. I don't want to use boost::Variant unless I really need to, 
and also I don't want to implement sth like this [Implementing a "variant" class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319216/implementing-a-variant-class)
because I am not familiar with template programming and I think my problem can be implemented in much simpler way.

Comment: Solutions depend on what exactly class A and B are. Are they PODs? Derived from the same base? Something else? Anyway, `boost::variant` is probably the way to go.

Comment: No they are not PODs and rather not derived from the same class.

Comment: How will you know what to do with them? If you need to store that information somewhere else, and perform different operations depending upon the type, then your design is all wrong.

Comment: I can just have another class that will call hasA on this class and do  sth with this object.

Answer (score 2):

For POD types, we have `union` (but the union won't remember *which* type you assigned, so also store this separately). This won't work for non-POD types. The major reason is because C++ doesn't know which one it should create upon construction / delete upon deletion of the union.

But a union can be used to hold pointers to the actual types. Then you have to care about construction and deletion yourself.

You could create something like this, which wraps this pointer-union and adds a convenient interface. Detailed explanation is written in the comments:

```
class EitherAorB {
    // We have to remember what we actually created:
    enum Which {
        A_Type,
        B_Type
    } m_which;

    // We store either a pointer to an A or to a B. Note that this union only
    // stores one pointer which is reused to interpret it as an A*, B* or void*:
    union {
        A *a;
        B *b;
        void *untyped; // Accessing the same pointer without looking at the type
    } m_ptr;

    // Additional stuff you want to store besides A and B
    const char *m_key;

public:
    EitherAorB(const char *key) {
        // Decision: Which type do we want to create?
        m_which = key[0] == 0 ? A_Type : B_Type;
        // Create the type (the cast to void* make the pointer "untyped"):
        m_ptr.untyped = m_which == A_Type ? (void*)new A() : (void*)new B();

        // Store additional stuff
        m_key = key;
    }
    ~EitherAorB() {
        // Since we stored the actual contents outside and point to them,
        // we have to free the memory. For this, we have to care about the
        // type again, so the correct destructor will be chosen. Deleting
        // the untyped pointer won't work here.
        if (m_which == A_Type) delete m_ptr.a;
        if (m_which == B_Type) delete m_ptr.b;
    }

    // These two functions can be used to query which type is stored.
    bool hasA() const {
        return m_which == A_Type;
    }
    bool hasB() const {
        return m_which == B_Type;
    }

    // These two functions can be used to query the pointers to the actual types.
    // I made them return a null pointer if the wrong getter was used.
    A *getA() {
        return m_which == A_Type ? m_ptr.a : 0;
    }
    B *getB() {
        return m_which == B_Type ? m_ptr.b : 0;
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation will lack memory if you copy an instance of `EitherAorB`. To fix this, either disable copying (by making the copy constructor and assignment operator private or disable them in C++11 using `= delete`), or implement the copy constructor and assignment operator which will deeply copy the pointee.

---

You said you aren't familiar with template programming. Making this implementation templated isn't difficult. Just put `template<typename A, typename B>` before the whole class definition; it should then work out of the box. However, don't move the implementations in `.cpp` files in this case; best is to keep them inlined as I wrote it.

Then, `A` and `B` aren't types but placeholders you assign types in your client code. I'd then rename the tempalte class to just `Either`, so your type names become something like `Either<This, That>`.

Comment: Note: If you don't want the getters to return pointers, you can also make them return references. But calling `getA` if `hasA` returned false is then undefined behavior...

Comment: Thanks for your nice response. I am not sure about this union with pointers, is it good practice? Would You write sth like this in your code or maybe write it some other way (boost::variant) ?

Comment: I once used a similar construct. But since I use the Qt framework in almost all of my C++ projects, and there is QVariant, I can use that one which provides great flexibility. This approach here is very efficient (although it can be even more efficient by directly storing either A or B in the class, but this requires some more tricks). I think I'd use it in production code, yes, but only after some unit tests ;). Especially, the missing copy constructor and assignment operator has to be added. I don't know what behavior you wanto, so I didn't write it.

Comment: A completely different approach is to use two `boost::optional` types. They either store something or nothing.

Comment: What does (void*) untyped do here ? If for example m_which = A_type then this line  m_ptr.untyped = m_which == A_Type ? (void*)new A() : (void*)new B()  will make m_ptr.a point to new A, or is there missing sth in the code? Anyway I guess I can just omit this untyped pointer and write if(m_which == A_Type) m_ptr.a = new A() else m_ptr.b = new B() ?

Comment: This is essentially the same. Remember that all members in a union share the same memory. So the untyped pointer is "the same" as the other two typed pointers. I just used it to implement the initialization in one line. It didn't work in the destructor, because the choice of the destructor to call depends on the pointer type which you pass to `delete`. You might think I could have written `delete (m_which == A_Type) ? m_ptr.a : m_ptr.b`, but unfortunately `?:` only accepts equal types.

Comment: At first point I made the copy constructor private but now I realized I need to use it to push the value into vector. The code looks like: EitherAorB c; c.Build(bytes); vector<EitherAorB>.push_back(c). I need to call method Build to know how many bytes the class EitherAorB have read. How do I implement this copy constructor to prevent memory leaking?

Comment: Both the assignment operator and copy constructor are necessary. I guess the copy constructor will just copy all the elements so it can stay with the implicit definition. Assignment operator is more complicated I guess

Comment: I don't understand what your `Build` method does. The best idea is to implement a very generic "either" type, independent from any special use case. Implement the copy and assignment by *deep-copying* the values which the pointers point to. Then, in a second design step, use this either type in your code. This will ensure re-usability and maintainability as much as possible.