# Multiple variant types map in embedded

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, types, embedded

I am working on an embedded application so need something lean. I am using a map to store parameters. These will either be int or float data types. Where have I gone wrong with this?

```
#include <string.h>

class parameter_types {
    typedef int parameter_int;
    typedef float parameter_float;
};

std::map<std::string, parameter_types*> mymap;

int map_test(char* return_string) {
  mymap["Circle"] = (int)1;
  mymap["Wibble"] = (float)0.4567;
  mymap["Triangle"] = 3.3;
  mymap["Square"] = 4;

  return 1;
}
```

I get the following compiler error:
   **Error: A value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "parameter_types *"**

I'm sure it's a basic mistake, but I'm not seeing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you tell the compiler that `mymap` is a map that maps `std::string` keys to `parameter_types` values. However `mymap["Circle"] = (int)1;` is telling the compiler to put an `int` value under a `std::string` key, which it of course can't, since the value type is `parameter_types`. You must put your `int` in an instance of `parameter_types` (which at this point does not have any member fields so you will have to add them) and then it will work.

As a possible solution you can use a `union` in the class like this:

```
class parameter_types {
    typedef int parameter_int;
    typedef float parameter_float;
    union value
    {
        parameter_int int_value;
        parameter_float float_value;
    };
};

parameter_types parameter;
parameter.value.int_value = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Rudolfs Bundulis. Are you sure about that issue? If I declare std::map<std::string, int> mymap3; and then do mymap3["Value1"]=(int)1; it compiles OK.

Comment: @user1228123 Then I guess you didn't understand the resposne:) That is exactly what I said - your map in the code maps `std::string` to `parameter_types`. `std::map<std::string. int> mymap3` maps `std::string` to `int` and that is why it works. If you need just to store and `int`, don't use the `parameter_types` variant wrapper, if you need different types, use a wrapper with a union inside.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a syntax error, here.

Theorically, you would need to set the type manually and store them as attribute:

```
class parameter_type
{
    int parameter_int;
    float parameter_float;
}

mymap["Circle"] = new parameter_type;
mymap["Circle"]->parameter_int = 10;
```

But, I don't think that it is what you want to do.

Then, if you need to store a variant type, you have multiple choices:

- You could use a lib which do all the type work like Boost (Boost.Variant or Boost.Any)
- You could make your proper implementation of Variant using templates.

As for the second, I recommend you to check this answer SO: [Implementing a "variant" class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319216/implementing-a-variant-class) which solves your question.

Comment: Hi Raito, thanks for your answer and sorry for delayed response. I was aware of boost but it didn't work in my embedded compiler and I was worried about the code size cost of adding a library as well. Does your suggestion of using the "new parameter_type" mean that each instance of the map has both an integer and a float, in which case it costs double the RAM?

Comment: Yes, it means that. You need to use a `union` to prevent the double cost, see the answer below, which can help you.