# How to create a Variant class similar to QVariant

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am trying to create a Variant class similar to Qt's QVariant. I've considered std::variant and std::any but unfortunately I need something analogous to the QVariant::value() function. But, I can't find a way to implement the function without getting errors like this:

```
note: candidate: template<class T> T Variant::value() const
         inline T value() const {
                  ^~~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319216/implementing-a-variant-class) seems to be what I want but I am trying to understand why that implementation works without receiving the "deduce template parameter 'T'" error on the return type. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here's my .H:

```
class Variant {

private:

enum VariantType {
    CHAR = 0,
    UCHAR,
    SCHAR,
    SHORT,
    USHORT,
    INT,
    UINT,
    LONG,
    ULONG,
    LONGLONG,
    ULONGLONG,
    BOOL,
    FLOAT,
    DOUBLE,
    LONGDOUBLE
};

public:

explicit Variant(int i);
explicit Variant(double d);

int ToInt() const;
double ToDouble() const;

private:

struct Internal {

    Internal(VariantType typeIn) :
        type(typeIn) {
    }

    union {
        char c;
        unsigned char uc;
        short s;
        signed char sc;
        unsigned short us;
        int i;
        unsigned int ui;
        long l;
        unsigned long ul;
        long long ll;
        unsigned long long ull;
        bool b;
        float f;
        double d;
        long double ld;
        void *ptr;
    } value;
    VariantType type;
};

Internal _data;

public:

  template<typename T>
  inline T value() const {
     // try to get int/double working first
     if (_data.type == VariantType::DOUBLE) {
        return _data.value.d;
     } else if (_data.type == VariantType::INT) {
        return _data.value.i;
     }
  }
};
```

And here's my .CPP:

```
Variant::Variant(int i) : _data(INT) {
    _data.value.i = i;
}

Variant::Variant(double d) : _data(DOUBLE) {
    _data.value.d = d;
}

int Variant::ToInt() const {
    return _data.value.i;
}

double Variant::ToDouble() const {
    return _data.value.d;
}
```

EDIT.

Comment: isn't this what std::get_if is for?

Comment: use `std::variant` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: Also, please make sure to post an [mcve] - emphasis on *minimal*   There's a ton of code here not required to reproduce your error.

Comment: @eyllanesc that's quite unhelpful.  he said he already considered it.

Comment: For example, you would use "Type erase". Code in stl `std::variant`.

Comment: @MrBin what part is PIMPL relevant to?

Comment: @xaxxon, described.

Comment: @xaxxon Improved question based on your comment.

Comment: the `std` equivalent of `QVariant::value` is [`std::any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast). Functions do not need to be members of a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from your call site, not the class definition. And the error tells you that `Variant::value<T>()` needs a `<T>`, but you did not provide any type argument with which to instantiate `value<T>`.

This same restriction applies to `QtVariant`, it's not unique to your class.